# MySQL: enumeration tables - use only one or many?

Tags: php, mysql, enumeration

Until now, I still made more enumerating tables with columns **ID** and **CODE** .. (money_type, payment_type, shipping_type ...).

Is it better to make every enumerating table separately or only one ? with columns **ID**, **CODE**, **TYPE** ... where type will be "money, payment, shipping".

In my system there will be minimal 50 enumerating tables..

Comment: Good question, not sure why someone down-voted it

Comment: because it's unclear, way too broad and poorly written. not to mention pretty much opinion based and probably a duplicate.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier if it's a duplicate, then mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a pure technical point of view, there is little against creating a giant lookup table for such purposes. However, there are some valid business reasons against doing so:

1. Security. You may not want the same user to be able to edit all lookup data. If you store all of them in a single table, then restricting access to certain records only can be difficult. Obviously, you can do that with views, but if you create as many views as lookup types, then what's the point of having a single table in the first place?
2. Configrability. In many cases these lookup tables may hold more data than just an id and a human readable description and the additional data would be specific for that given parameter only. For example, on a tax code lookup table you may be able to specify that the given tax code is only applicable to domestic transactions only, and not applicable on cross-border ones (such as VAT). If you have a giant table holding all configuration data, then such customization is a lot more difficult.

Obviously, if the purpose of having these lookup tables is to provide a human readable description (e.g. a definitions table you can use for GUI), then you can have a single table for that. Otherwise I would go for the 1 lookup table per parameter approach, even if you need to have 50 lookup tables.